# Delete every other node from a linked list given 1->2->3->4 to get 2->4?

Tags: c

I have looked in other forums how to delete every other node, but they always get the result 1->3 and I want 2->4. I am having trouble with this. I have spent hours looking at this and any help would be appreciated. I added a couple of `printf` statements to see where I am going wrong. This is the output I am getting:

```
17 3 8 8 20 13 15 17 10 13


current: 17
forward: 3
free: 17
current: 8
forward->next: 8
-------End------

free: 8
current: 8
forward->next: 20
-------End------

free: 8
current: 20
forward->next: 13
-------End------

free: 20
current: 13
forward->next: 15
-------End------

free: 13
current: 15
forward->next: 17
-------End------

free: 15
current: 17
forward->next: 10
-------End------

free: 17
current: 10
forward->next: 13
-------End------

free: 10
current: 13
```

Here's my code:

```
node *deleteEveryOther(node *head)
{
    node *forward, *current;

    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    current = head;
    printf("\n\ncurrent: %d\n", current->data);
    forward = head->next;
    printf("forward: %d\n", forward->data);

    while(current != NULL && forward != NULL)
    {
        printf("free: %d\n", current->data);
        free(current);

        current = forward->next;
        printf("current: %d\n", current->data);

        forward->next = current->next;
        printf("forward->next: %d\n", forward->next->data);
        //if(previous->next != NULL)
            //previous = previous->next;

        printf("-------End------\n\n");
    }

    return head;
}
```

Here I edited (applying the algorithm I saw) the code a bit:

node *deleteEveryOther(node *head)
{
    node *previous, *current;

```
if (head == NULL)
    return NULL;

previous = head;
current = head->next;

free(previous);
previous = current;
current = head->next;

while(current != NULL && previous != NULL)
{
    previous->next = current->next;

    free(current);

    previous = previous->next;

    if(previous != NULL)
        current = previous->next;

}

return head;
```

}

// -----------------RECURSIVE APPROACH--------------------------

```
void deleteEveryOtherRecursively(node *head)`
{ 
    if (head == NULL)
    return;

    node *current = head;

    if (current == NULL)
        return;

    node *forward = head->next;
    head = current->next = forward->next;

    free(current);

    deleteEveryOtherRecursively(head);
}
```

Comment: what if list had 6 nodes? then what would you want your list to be `2->4` or `2->6`

Comment: If it had 6 nodes like 1->2->3->4->5->6, then I would want my output to be 2->4->6.

Comment: okay so you want only the even nodes right :) @user6134432

Comment: Well I want keep all the ones at even positions. For example, 33->57->88->103->5->80, then I would get 57->103->80.

Comment: are you obliged to only use a single linked list? because what you are trying to achieve can be easily achieved using doubly linked list

Comment: Well this is just for practice, I would like to do it with singly linked list and then in the future possibly work with doubly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can free first node and get the new head outside the while loop. Then free all alternative node inside the while loop.

I have slightly changed the code.

```
struct node *deleteEveryOther(struct node *head) 
{ 
    struct node *forward, *current;

    /* If empty list */
    if (head == NULL)
            return NULL;

    /* Free first element */
    current = head;
    forward = head->next;
    free(current);

    /* Get new head */
    current = forward;
    head = current;

    /* Now remove all next elements */
    while (current != NULL) {
            forward = current->next; 
            if (forward != NULL) {
                    current->next = forward->next;
                    free(forward);
            }
            current = current->next;
    }

    /* Return new head */
    return head;
}
```

In your code, there are few mistakes. Like you are not updating new `head`, but returning same old `head`. Also you were dereferencing  some pointers without checking if they are `NULL` (in your printf statements).

This can also be done recursively. In you version, you are not returning head, (a `void` function), which is an issue. There are few other issues as well. You can compare below code with your code and see the differences.

```
/* deleteEveryOtherRecursively: recursively delete odd numbered nodes */
struct node *deleteEveryOtherRecursively(struct node *head) 
{ 
    struct node *forward;

    /* Base case    */
    if (head == NULL)
            return NULL;

    forward = head->next; /* Get the next node in forward */ 
    free(head);           /* free old head */
    head = forward;       /* new head points to next elem */

    if (head != NULL)     /* recur down if needed */
            head->next = deleteEveryOtherRecursively(head->next);

    return head;          /* return new head */
}
```

Comment: I am trying to fully understand the code. Why do we do the head = current line?

Comment: @user6134432 So, that we are updating `head` of the linked list. `head` points to first node in the linked list. We are returning this new `head` at the last line as `return head;` Now, since we are removing all `odd` numbered nodes (i.e. node 1, node 3, etc), so now `head` should point to node 2 of original linked list (or NULL if there was only 1 node in the original linked list). And at the time when `head = current;` is executed, `current` is pointing to 2nd node in the original linked list (or NULL if there was only 1 node in the original linked list).

Comment: Ok that makes sense! If we were to do this recursively would it be a lot easier just wondering? I will try to do it recursively to see.

Comment: @user6134432 `Easier` has different meanings in different contexts !! Anyways, if you mean, less lines of code, then yes, I could write a  recursive version in less lines. But then again, someone else could write an iterative version which is less lines than my recursive version. But, yes in general, recursive versions are usually shorter than iterative version. Both iterative and recursive versions have their own pros and cons. You can find that in google. But yes writing recursive will be a good practice.

Comment: @user6134432 Also, if you are interested, this page   http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/ has links for good `linked-list` problems. Some of them require recursive solution. Also same page has link for `binary-tree` problems, which are best solved by using recursive functions. I enjoyed doing those problems. You can solve them if you like.

Comment: Thanks for sharing I will try to solve these as well. They will be good practice since I'm a newbie. I attempted the recursive approach, and it's not working I feel like I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I added the recursive approach all the way at the end of my post since I couldn't paste it here.

Comment: @user6134432 There are multiple issues with your code. First you are not returning new head, second you are again deferencing pointers without checking if they are NULL or not, and there are other issues too. I am sure if you do the linked list questions given in the url i gave before then you will be able to write this correctly. It seems you are really interested in learning, so it is best if you solve all 15-20 questions in that. It has good explaination to linked list operations.

Comment: Okay will do that. So I should make this return a pointer to a node to update the head?

Comment: yes you should return a pointer, (or else, pass the pointer to head, that is `node **` if you want the function to return void). I have updated with my recursive version. You can compare with yours and see what you were missing.

Comment: Sorry if I am bombarding you with questions. Just trying to make sure I am understanding; why do we need the head->next  in the head->next = deleteEveryOtherRecursively(head->next); ?

Comment: Consider der r 4 nodes in ur list. So in first call to `recursive` funciton, (1) we free original `head`, then (2) `head` will now pointto node 2 because we do `head = forward`. At this point  head->next` points to `third` element in the original list. But we need `head->next` to point to the `fourth` node in the list. So we do `head->next = recursive(head->next)` so that `recursive` will delete 3rd node and return pointer to 4th node. Please go through that linked list tutorial i gave u b4. It has a VERY good section on making memory drawings, which is so good, that you will thank me :).

Comment: I drew out diagrams and followed your explanation and it's clear now! Thank you so much for helping me out, you've been awesome. Are there any books or other resources you recommend for computer science topics in general? I want to learn as much as I can.

Comment: Glad to know that I was of help. Why dont you accept the answer, hehe? Anycase, I am not a CS guy, but I can suggest two things. `The C programming language 2nd edition` , and `GNU/Linux`. Both of these are just awesome. http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/Kernighan-Ritchie/C-Programming-Ebook.pdf link for C book. This book is written by `Ritchie` - the guy who invented C - if this can be a motivation :p

Answer (score 1):

You may want to delete the first node, then apply the algorithm to the remaining linked list. This is one way it should work, and it's the simplest in my view.

Comment: I was thinking of that so just free the first node outside the while loop?

Comment: It is...any other suggestions?

Comment: @user6134432 not really. I have given the simplest one which shouldn't fail if done properly. When removing the first node, are you also updating the head correctly?

Comment: I added the code I tried here. It's after the first code. I can't really paste it here.

Comment: You did NOT update the head too when doing that initial remove. Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: When removing the head, of course it is bound to change.